# Allowing a Node Form to Submit More than Once

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

Using Drupal 7, I am running into an issue with Drupal not allowing node forms to be submitted twice. The scenario:

- I display a node form and use Drupal's ajax framework to handle the submit via the use-ajax-submit feature.
- The first time I submit the form, it works, no problem.
- The second time I submit the form, I get the following message:

  "The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or you have already submitted modifications using this form. As a result, your changes cannot be saved."

I understand this is expected behavior, and am trying to find a way around it. I seem to remember there being a form attribute in Drupal 6 that would allow multiple submits when the form was built, but can't find anything about it with Drupal 7.

Would love any advice anyone may have to share.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this! Looking in the node module, it turned out that `node_validate` does a check on the last submitted time based on values in the `form_state` variable. I wrote a custom validate handler for the form, which bypassed the `node_validate` function and allowed node forms to submit multiple times.

```
 /**
 * Sets up a node form so that it can be submitted more than once through an ajax interface
 * @param unknown_type $form
 * @param unknown_type $form_state
 */
function MYMODULE_allow_multisubmit (&$form, &$form_state){

  // set this as a custom submit handler within a form_alter function
  // set the changed value of the submission to be above the last updated time
  // to bypass checks in the node_validate
  $check = node_last_changed($form_state['values']['nid']);
  $form_state['values']['changed'] = $check + 120;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

hook_allow_multisubmit don't existe in drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem i ran into recently, so i will add a 'fuller' version of Mark Weitz's answer which does indeed work.

First you will need to alter the node form for the content you type you required

```
//Implements hook_form_alter()
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

    //Check form is the node add/edit form for the required content type
    if($form_id == "MYCONTENTTYPE_node_form"){

        //Append our custom validation function to the forms validation array
        //Note; We must use array_unshift so our function is called first.
        array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'my_custom_validation_function');

    }

}
```

Now to define are custom validation function which will fix the error:

*"The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or you have already submitted modifications using this form. As a result, your changes cannot be saved."*

```
//Our custom validation function
function my_custom_validation_function($form, &$form_state){

    //Drupal somewhere in this validation chain will check our $form_state
    //variable for when it thinks the node in question was last changed,
    //it then determins when the node was actually changed and if the $form_state
    //value is less than the drupal value it throws the 'Cant edit' error.
    //To bypass this we must update our $form_state changed value to match the actual
    //last changed value. Simple stuff really...

    //Lets do the above ^^
    $form_state['values']['changed'] = node_last_changed($form_state['values']['nid']);

    //Any other extra validations you want to do go here.

}
```

Obviously this is not without its risks as now for our chosen content type people are able to overwrite each others work. Assuming they are editing the node at the same time.